# How to install grive tools on 16.04 or later

Tags: 16.04, ppa, grive

I see there are [working packages](https://launchpad.net/~thefanclub/+archive/ubuntu/grive-tools/+packages) for:

- Utopic
- Vivid
- Trusty

But none for Xenial or later. Despite the fact that the code is in python and bash.

Is the PPA auto build broken for it?

I cant find a way to drop a question on the PPA either even after login there...

Edit: as pointed by N0rbert, [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012861/589343) is about grive, but the questioner's subject is not about it... that must be the reason I didnt find his answer in the 1st place. My question is objectively to the point (although his answer is better than my answer, the duplication is about the question, and my question is therefore not a duplicate).

Comment: @N0rbert your answer is about grive tools, but the question is not, that's why i didnt find it and had to create my own question... my question is to the point.

Answer (score 1):

I had found (just before asking) an anwer but as it was about 6 months w/o grive tools, so I am happy to share that it works and how:

1) Install "gdebi".
2) Download the latest grive tools, i used the utopic one.
3) Install the deb file thru gdebi, it will download and install all required dependencies. (I actually used synaptic to install most deps before using gdebi).

Do not run the grive setup if you already had installed it before. Just run the "google drive indicator" directly, and setup auto start on its preferences if needed.

See a more detailed answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1012861/589343